# Need help to link vaccine centers to admin, mongo db, mean stack project

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, mongoose, mean-stack

hi i am new to developing a mean stack project, my task that im stuck at is i have two collections one as user for admin and other for center for vaccine center my task is to register an admin to a healthcare center but im not sure how to link these as the admin is required to see healthcare centers that are registered select and then register them into the center

user.js (mongoose schema)
,,,

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  username: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
  password: {type: String, required: true},
  fullname: {type: String, required: true},
  email: {type: String, required: true},
  staffid: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
  center: {type: String, required: true},
});
userSchema.plugin(uniqueValidator);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

,,,

center.js

,,,

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');


const postSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  cname: {type: String, required: true},
  caddr: {type: String, required: true}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Centers', postSchema);
```

,,,

user.model.service

,,,

```
export interface User{
  id: string;
  fname: string;
  uname: string;
  email: string;
  pass: string;
  staffid: string;
  center: string;


}
```

,,,

signup-component.html (i plan to display the list of center names as dropdown so the admin can select center name when they register the account)
,,,

```
<mat-form-field appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Select</mat-label>
    <mat-select >
      <mat-option name="center" *ngFor="let post of posts" value="post">{{post.cname}}</mat-option>

</mat-select>
```

,,,

app.js
,,,

```
app.post('/api/user/signup', (req, res, next) => {
  bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10)
  .then(hash => {
    const user = new User ({
      username: req.body.username,
      password: hash,
      fullname: req.body.fullname,
      email: req.body.email,
      staffid: req.body.staffid,
      center: req.body.center




    });
    user.save()
    .then(result => {
      res.status(201).json({
        message: 'user registered',
        result: result
      });
    })
    .catch(err =>{
      res.status(500).json({
        error:err
      });
  });
});
});
```

,,,

Answer (score 0):

From what you describe, I think you need *three* database tables or *three* `mongoose.Schema`s:

- one for the vaccination centers: like in your `center.js`
- one for the (admin) users: like in your `user.js`, but *without* the `center` property
- and one for assignment of users to centers:

```js
mongoose.Schema({
  user: {type: schema.type.objID, ref: "Users", required: true},
  center: {type: schema.type.objID, ref: "Centers", required: true}
});
```

The extra association schema is needed if one user can be assigned to several vaccination centers.

Does that help with your requirements?

Comment: oh alright thanks i will follow that, i searched and  found somewhere something like , center {type: schema.type.objID, ref:'Centers') as you suggested for the third table should this be added?

Comment: Using object IDs instead of strings sounds much cleaner, I have edited my answer accordingly.